# When $\{ \frac{n^p}{(\log n)^{rp}} \}$is bounded sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Define sequence $$a_n =\frac{n}{(\log n)^r}$$ with $r>0, n\in \mathbb N.$

> Can we find  the power  of $a_n$ so that $\{a_n^p\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is a bounded sequence?  In other words, can we find generic $p\in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ so  that $|a_n^p| \leq C$ for  all  $n >N$? Or can we find relation between $r$ and $p$ so that $\{a_n^p\}$ is bounded?

Comment: Since $a_n \to \infty$ you require $p \le 0$ in which case $a_n^p \to 0$ (or $1$ if $p=0$)  and is consequently bounded.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Since for any $\alpha,\beta>0$, we know that $\;\log^\alpha n=o(n^\beta)$, what do you think $p$ can be?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $a_n\to\infty$, because for any $r>0$ it is $\log(x)<x^r$ for all $x>x_0$ for some $x_0>0$.

If $p>0$, since the function $f(t)=t^p$ satisfies $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=\infty$, $a_n^p)$ cannot be bounded.

If $p=0$, since $t^0=1$, $(a_n^p)$ is constantly $1$, thus bounded.

If $p<0$, then we have the sequence $\frac{1}{a_n^{|p|}}$ and by the first case this converges to $0$, so it is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $a_n = \frac{n}{Ln(n)}$ diverges due to Hopital's law.
On the other hand $Ln(a_n^p) = p(Ln(n) - r Ln(Ln(n)))$ sequence is diverge to $+\infty$ or
$-\infty$ obviously. Thus for every negative $p$ the sequence $a_n^p$ converges to $0$.